# Creating Numerical Recipes random number generator in Python

Tags: python, c++, random, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I would like to generate random numbers from the U[0,1] distribution. I am trying to recreate the random number generator from Numerical Recipes Chapter 7.1.  Unfortunately, my C++ is not particularly strong and so I am having some issues following the code! I was wondering if someone could help clarify my understanding of really what is happening here. In C++ the code is provided as:

```
struct Ran {
    Ullong u, v, w;
    Ran(Ullong j) : v(4101842887655102017LL), w(1) {
        u = j ^ v; int64();
        v = u; int64();
        w = v; int64();
    }
    inline Ullong int64() {
        u = u * 2862933555777941757LL + 7046029254386353087LL;
        v ^= v >> 17; v ^= v << 31; v ^= v >> 8;
        w = 4294957665U*(w & 0xffffffff) + (w >> 32);
        Ullong x = u ^ (u << 21); x ^= x >> 35; x ^= x << 4;
        return (x + v) ^ w;
    }
    inline Doub doub() { return 5.42101086242752217E-20 * int64(); }
    inline Uint int32() { return (Uint)int64(); }
};
```

My understanding is this:

```
Ran(Ullong j) : v(4101842887655102017LL), w(1) {
        u = j ^ v; int64();
        v = u; int64();
        w = v; int64();
    }
```

This is our initialisation. `j` here is our seed. `v` is set to be a really big prime number. `^` is a bit-wise XOR operator and so this provides our first level of randomness as we shuffle `u`, `v` and `w`.

Beyond this I start getting confused.

```
inline Ullong int64() {
        u = u * 2862933555777941757LL + 7046029254386353087LL;
        v ^= v >> 17; v ^= v << 31; v ^= v >> 8;
        w = 4294957665U*(w & 0xffffffff) + (w >> 32);
        Ullong x = u ^ (u << 21); x ^= x >> 35; x ^= x << 4;
        return (x + v) ^ w;
    }
```

In particular, I don't understand what

```
    v ^= v >> 17;
```

does. I think it is bit-shifting `v` by 17 digits to the right and then performing XOR of the original `v` against this and then saving this output as `v`.

I also don't understand

```
w = 4294957665U*(w & 0xffffffff) + (w >> 32);
```

at all. A quick search [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/8bux05/is_0xffffffff_1_or_4294967295/) says `0xffffffff` is either -1 or a big number but I still don't really understand what this line is doing (other than some bit-wise operations).

Finally, I believe that this line:

```
inline Doub doub() { return 5.42101086242752217E-20 * int64(); }
```

is returning the random number between 0 and 1.

If anyone could correct, clarify or confirm what I have here I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This code looks a bit adventurous. But, maybe, I'm just confused that a function called int... returns an unsigned. (Bugs due to wrong signed-ness can hit you hard. That's why, I never would have this idea.) However, have you considered to use [Random sampling (numpy.random)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html) instead? (That said, I somewhere must have the Numerical Recipes in the book shelf somewhere...) ;-)

Comment: Concerning `v ^= v >> 17;`. That's the abbreviation of `v = v ^ (v >> 17);`.
`w & 0xffffffff` is just a bit masking (bit-wise and). All upper bits are cleared while the lower bits are kept.

Comment: Concerning _`inline Doub doub() { return 5.42101086242752217E-20 * int64(); }` is returning the random number between 0 and 1._ Yes, it seems so: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbbe2bd0eb651af6). (Though, a test with 10 numbers isn't a proof, of course.) ;-)

Comment: Maybe, this would count as "proof": [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08f69294230c21df). (I considered the min. of `uint64_t` as trivial case - it's 0, and hence, the multiplication is 0 as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Scheff's Cat, all super helpful answers. I've knocked up something that seems like it's working in Python but I've also taken your advice and gone slightly less adventurous with my random number generation for the time being.